# Convert Houdini Matrix To Blender Matrix?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a Houdini matrix to Blender matrix so that when the matrix is applied in Blender the camera faces the same direction and is in the same place as it was in Houdini.

I am looking for some kind of "black-box" python function that will accept a Houdini matrix and return a valid Blender matrix. Like shown in this math image. 
[image]

Comment: I can't figure out what a Houdini-matrix is. Googling doesn't help, can you provide a link? is it some other program or something?

Comment: There is a utility function for importing/exporting available in [this module](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy_extras.io_utils.html#bpy_extras.io_utils.axis_conversion). To deal with matrices in general there is [mathutils](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/mathutils.html#module-mathutils)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies. I also got replies on [BlenderArtists](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?337776-Assign-a-Houdini-Matrix-To-A-Blender-Object&p=2654149&viewfull=1#post2654149) as well. I finally found a solution that works for me so I thought i'd post it here for others to use.

Run this code in the Blender default scene and the camera will jump from one location to another. The new location is defined by the string that holds the Houdini matrix.

```
import bpy, math
from mathutils import Vector,Matrix

def applyTransform(sMatrix, passedOb):
    if passedOb != None:
        tmp = eval(sMatrix)
        mtx = Matrix(tmp)
        passedOb.location = [mtx[3][0],-mtx[3][1],mtx[3][2]]        # Flip Z and Y axis.
        mtx.transpose()                                             # From BL Stack user.
        rot_x_neg90 = Matrix.Rotation(math.pi/2.0, 4, 'X')          # From Kastoria.
        passedOb.matrix_world = rot_x_neg90 * mtx                   # From Kastoria.

# Matrix string from Houdini object.
s = "[[0.900496, 3.27826e-007, -0.434865, 0], [-0.117881, 0.962558, -0.244102, 0], [0.418583, 0.271075, 0.866779, 0], [5.32776, 2.57303, 7.33473, 1]]"
ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
applyTransform(s,ob)
```

Comment: You may now accept your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the [hou-matrix4](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini13.0/hom/hou/Matrix4) , but if you're just asking how to flip the z-axis try this:

```
import mathutils

def convert( mat ):
    houdini = mat.copy()
    houdini[2][2] = -houdini[2][2]
    return houdini

blender_mat = mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4)

print( blender_mat )
print( convert( blender_mat ))
```

Prints:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
```